# Run query based on variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, plpgsql

In PG, I need to get results from a different query based on the value of a variable.

I tried something like this -

```
do $$
declare myVar int;
select <something> into myVar;
if myVar = 1 then
    select col1 from myTable;
else
    select col2 from myTable;
end if;
end $$;
```

This gives me:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

Now, I can't do `case` because depending on myVar, myTable might have the column col1 or col2; not both. Using case will fail with "column does not exist" since it considers the whole statement and notices the non existing column.

I'm hoping IF-ELSE will help by avoiding the block with the incorrect (non-existing) column

Comment: I think the error message means that you need to `SELECT col1 INTO result FROM myTable. As is, the result of your conditional `SELECT` is discarded.

Comment: How do I view the final results output of my ```select col1 from tbl``` or ```select col2 from tbl```?

Comment: I say this without knowing what you're trying to accomplish, but I would probably bundle it up as a function returning col1%TYPE or something, then call it with `SELECT myFunction(myVar)`

Comment: Aah. Makes sense to convert it to a function. But I was wondering if I could do it without a function; since I'll be running this on a client's DB. I don't want to have extra objects there. I could drop function too. But I'd be doing this periodically. So without function would be ideal.

Comment: You don't need `IF`. You can convert the `select <something> into myVar;` line into a `WHERE EXISTS ( something_else)` clause. Or: where not exists() for the ELSE part.

Comment: You cannot get the results directly from an DO block. You can insert them into a table but then you need to select from that table. Otherwise you need a function.  If he task is to just retrieve data from the client's DB then perhaps you can setup a dblink(?) or a foreign data wrapper.